# styled components / react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

Im working on a simple button example which i plan to extend. I have added a new button and included some constants as well. so far so good. In case i want to use more button versions like version1, version2, version3 of the same button with some styles changed like the background color. How should i do that? And how should they be exported?

```
const PrimaryButton = styled.button`
  font: inherit;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: ${buttonBackgroundColor};
  color: ${buttonColor};
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  border-color: ${colors.blueLight};
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline:none;
  :hover {
    background-color: ${colors.blueLight};
  }
`;
```

Maybe it is possible to extend the button (how?) or does it make more sense to add different components for each button? For my typography i have use "extend". That works. How would that be for the different button versions? Is there a similar way?

```
export const H1 = styled.h1`
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
`
export const H2 = H1.withComponent('h2').extend`
  font-size: 24px;
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was working as i added a new component. I imported the PrimaryButton into the new defined component called "Version2".

```
import PrimaryButton from './primary';
```

From here i updated the PrimaryButton like this:

```
const Version2 = PrimaryButton.extend`background-color: red;`
```

This has the advantage that we have a master component for a button. Now we are able to extend the master with diversity of additional styles. In my case background-color.

With the help of

```
export default Version2;
```

we are now able to add this button called "Version2" into our render function like:

```
<PrimaryButton>ClickMe!</PrimaryButton>
<Version2>ClickMe!</Version2>
```

and now we get the different buttons. And it´s very modular and clean as well.